# How to write the distance matrix of a matrix in a matrix algebra form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider $\boldsymbol{X}_{m \times n}$ consisting $m$ vectors with $n$ dimnesions, I want to write $\boldsymbol{D}_{m \times m}$ which is the matrix whose entries are distances between each two vectors of $\boldsymbol{X}_{m \times n}$. In other words, I want $\boldsymbol{D} = f(\boldsymbol{X})$. I am wondering what's the $f()$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\odot$ denote the Hadamard product and $J$ the *all-ones* matrix with the same dimensions as $X$.

The distance between the $j^{th}$ and $k^{th}$ rows is given by
$$\eqalign{
d_{jk}^2 &= \|x_j - x_k\|^2_2 \\
 &= x_j^2 + x_k^2 - 2x_j\,x_k \\
 &= x_j^2\,{\tt1}_k + {\tt1}_j\,x_k^2 - 2x_j\,x_k \\
}$$
which can be written in matrix form as
$$\eqalign{
D\odot D \;=\; (X\odot X)J^T + J(X\odot X)^T - 2XX^T \\\\
}$$
If you want the distances between the columns, it's
$$\eqalign{
C\odot C \;=\; (X\odot X)^TJ + J^T(X\odot X) - 2X^TX \\\\
}$$